# pysnmp cmdGen - How to feed OIDs from a variable

Tags: python, pysnmp

I have a list of SNMP OIDs I want to return but I cannot substitute the variable for the OIDs in the command. I have even tried wrapping the variable in an eval, and combining with ObjectType and ObjectIdentity with no success.

I have taken the base config template from [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/get-v2c.html) and edited for my purposes.

Here's the block of config in full:

```
cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(
    cmdgen.UsmUserData(user, 
                    authKey=authKe, 
                    privKey=privKe, 
                    authProtocol=authProto, 
                    privProtocol=privProto, 
                    securityEngineId=None
            ),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((sHost, 161)),
    (_OID),
```

In place of `(_OID),` the following substitutions all work:

```
    cmdgen.MibVariable('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0'),
    cmdgen.MibVariable('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0'),
    cmdgen.MibVariable('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0'),
    cmdgen.MibVariable('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0'),
    cmdgen.MibVariable(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)),
    '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0',
```

All the above can be added as a complete block, individually, or any other combination. The _OID Variable takes a list of OIDs and converts it to a string to look like this: `'1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0',`. I suspect there may even be a way to use the list directly.

I know I can wrap getCmd in a `for` to do it and, so long as I instantiate the engine beforehand, there's is little performance hit, as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654132/reuse-getcmd-object-in-pysnmp), but I like the cmdgen method as it is clean, and I suspect wrapping this would be expensive.

How can I use the _OID variable to dynamically set the OIDs required?

pysnmp Version 4.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your positional arguments in a sequence, just use the `*` operator to unpack them into function's positional arguments.

```
_oids = ('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0',
         '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0')

cmdGen.getCmd(
    cmdgen.UsmUserData(
        user, 
        authKey=authKe, 
        privKey=privKe, 
        authProtocol=authProto, 
        privProtocol=privProto
    ),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((sHost, 161)),
    *[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)) for oid in _oids]
)
```

Comment: Perfect! I was not aware of the `*` operator. Every day's a school day!